# How to add a tick symbol to AutoCompleteTextView item suggestion?

Tags: kotlin, sharedpreferences, autocompletetextview, google-places-autocomplete

I already have a AutoCompleteTextView with custom layout and adapter. How can I control the visibility of a tick symbol next to each item to show if the item has already been added? By added I mean, it's compared with another list that's fetched from storage that I compare with the AutoCompleteTextView suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed to do was to have the tick icon in the custom layout be `View.INVISIBLE`by default. Then in the `getView()` method of the custom adapter, change the visibility according to the requirement for that specific situation. The point is, the `getView()` method is responsible for any changes to related to the UI of the items.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean is an Exposed Dropdown Menus, available in the latest [material design library](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/).

Please read the documentation about how to implement it: https://material.io/develop/android/components/menu/